# POST API Rest JSON

Tags: html5, json, api, rest

Tenho um formulário em `HTML` que deverá enviar dados para um servidor em formato `JSON`. Como eu formato esses dados do input e envio para uma API Rest os dados em JSON da maneira em que descrevi abaixo?

Ao meu ver necessito de fazer um POST, a dificuldade é formatar da maneira em que se deve ser enviada.

Formulário:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nome">Nome</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" placeholder="Enter name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pw">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pw" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
      Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

O servidor deverá receber os dados em JSON da seguinte maneira

```
{
    "nome": "Ricardo",
    "pw": "01023423sdqz1",
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Eu trocaria o button para type="button" para não dar o post completo e no onclick do button eu chamaria este código abaixo:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://coloqueaquisuaurl.com/caminho',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { nome: $('#nome').val(), pw: $('#pw').val() },
}).done(function (data) {
    alert('entrei aqui');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Se você utilizar php, pode formatar da seguinte forma:

```
$json = array('nome' => $_POST['nome'], 'pw' => $_POST['password']);
$json = json_encode($json)
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você está usando jQuery, a resposta é simples:

```
var conteudoDoForm = $("form").serialize();
```

Caso não, você pode utilizar este método mencionado no [Stack Overflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24435566/1845714):

```
function serialize(form, evt){
    var evt    = evt || window.event;
    evt.target = evt.target || evt.srcElement || null;
    var field, query='';
    if(typeof form == 'object' && form.nodeName == "FORM"){
        for(i=form.elements.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            field = form.elements[i];
            if(field.name && field.type != 'file' && field.type != 'reset'){
                if(field.type == 'select-multiple'){
                    for(j=form.elements[i].options.length-1; j>=0; j--){
                        if(field.options[j].selected){
                            query += '&' + field.name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(field.options[j].value).replace(/%20/g,'+');
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if((field.type != 'submit' && field.type != 'button') || evt.target == field){
                        if((field.type != 'checkbox' && field.type != 'radio') || field.checked){
                            query += '&' + field.name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(field.value).replace(/%20/g,'+');
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return query.substr(1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Você vai ter que usar `javascript` para isso.

Segue um exemplo

```js
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function(){
  let jsonArr = {
    "nome": document.getElementById('nome').value,
    "senha": document.getElementById('pw').value
  }
  
  console.log(jsonArr)
  
  axios.post('SUA URL', jsonArr)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

```html
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nome">Nome</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" placeholder="Enter name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pw">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pw" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
      Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.16.2/axios.min.js"></script>
```